# Recognizing malicious URL attempts against your website

Tags: webserver, known-vulnerabilities

On serveral websites I've run, I periodically see URLs run against my servers that look like this:

/url_result?ctw_=sT,een_j...tdmlydXMtc2NhbS1lb........

Does anyone recognize it? I've tried to Google related URLs.

I suppose I'm expecting to see "attempting to find a vulnerability in x CMS".

But I don't see much.

Comment: Would you please post the whole URL?

Answer (score 1):

[Googling for "url_result ctw_"](https://www.google.com/search?q=url_result+ctw_) I found "I think it is yahoo japan search result for some music search and it also does translation into japanese language from english.
honyaku.yahoofs.jp is yahoo japan search engine and when you go to that address it is yahoo japan transtext site (text translation)" ([here](http://www.webmasterforums.com/general-lounge/5660-hmmmm-someone-made-mirror-my-webpage.html)), and I also see ['real people' referencing it](http://www.japan-guide.com/forum/quereadisplay.html?0+74201), and those references are OK.

There are many (838000) hits, it's obviously a common referer.

Comment: fascinating. thank you. I saw all the japanese results but couldn't figure out why I would be getting them. thanks for your time.